# how to insert double byte to DB without add N into the literal

Tags: sql, csv, stored-procedures, unicode, double-byte

a lot of people say you can do this:

```
declare @str        nvarchar(255);
declare @finalValue nvarchar(255);

set @str        = N'好使';
set @finalValue = @str;
```

But this is not my case. What I want to do is something like this:

```
  declare @str        nvarchar(255);
  declare @finalValue nvarchar(255);

  set @str        = '好使'     ;
  set @finalValue = 'N'+ @str ;

  print @finalValue;
```

because the value `@str` actually is from somewhere else(CSV).

In a stored procedure, I got the `@str` value from CSV and it is double byte (Chinese/Japanese), which is saved correctly) and I want to add `N` before inserting it in the DB table (without the `N`, it displays as `??` in the table.)

How can I add the N?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK.

The `N` you're talking about is not a function that does anthing. It's a part of the syntax of SQL that defines string literals.

**Single-byte string literals**

A single-byte string literal consists of a lead-in single quote (`'`) , followed by zero or more other characters other than a single quote, followed by a lead-out single quote (`'`). To remove ambiguity, any embedded single quotes are *escaped* by doubling them. The *lexical value* of a string literal does not include the lead-in/lead-out quotes nor the doubled internal escapes, so the string literal

```
'That''s crazy!`
```

has the lexical value

```
That's crazy!
```

Such a string literal is defined as a single-byte string as interpreted by the default collation of the database. Further, each character occupies a single byte.

Consequently, an expression such as

```
select *
from foo
where some_column = 'That''s crazy!'
```

is **exactly the same as**

```
declare @temp char(13) = 'That''s crazy!'

select *
from foo
where some_column = @temp
```

Notes: while you can put unicode characters, such as Katagana or Hiragana in a single-byte string literal, you're unlikely to get what you expect.

**Double-Byte (Unicode) String Literals**

Double-byte (Unicode) string literals are defined in the same way, except that the literal is prefixed with `N` to indicate that it's special:

```
`N'That''s crazy!'
```

again has the lexical value

```
That's crazy!
```

but in this case, each character occupies **two bytes** and is Unicode UCS-2 encoded.

And again, an expression such as

```
select *
from foo
where some_column = N'That''s crazy!'
```

is **exactly the same as**

```
declare @temp nchar(13) = 'That''s crazy!'

select *
from foo
where some_column = @temp
```

So...your question "How can I add the N?" makes no sense. The N isn't a function that changes anything. You can't apply it to a variable (you already did in declare the variable to be of type `nchar` or `nvarchar`.

You problem lies in how you are reading your CSV file and how you're getting the data into your `@str` variable.

Comment: I put the value of '@str' in a csv file and save as unicode txt, and then change the extension back to csv. Then I use pentaho  kettle process it. A transformation file is associated with a SP, in the SP '@str' has the value from csv file and insert it into db.

Comment: I know it's an old thread, but thanks @Nicholas Carey for the explanation. I learned something today!